# Proving a set a Field

Tags: abstract-algebra

Would the proving of a set is a field be the same as with a vector space? Would we need to prove that the $8$ properties hold, and that it is closed under scalar multiplication and addition?

Comment: Yes. Though in addition to having a set you also need the two binary operations to be defined in either case.

Comment: More or less.  The axioms may be worded slightly different.  Prove that addition and multiplication (not scalar but between two elements) are binary operations are closed.  That they are associative and commutative.  That one element is an additive identity (0) exists and that another element is a multiplicative identity (1). That every element has a additive inverse.  And every non-zero element has a multiplicative inverse.  And that the distributive law of $a(b+c) = ab + ac$ always holds.

Comment: Bob, do you mean to say in the same way as you would for a vector space?

Answer (score 4):

No. The axioms for field and vector space are different, even if they have some similarities.

Answer (score 0):

To prove a set $S$ is a field you must show:

A) There have been defined two binary operations, $\cdot$ and $+$ on the set.

$*$ is a binary operation if for any two $a,b \in S$ then $a*b =c$ for some $s \in S$. (Consistantly annd unambiguously.)

*Any* function of $S \times S \rightarrow S$ can be a binary operation.  There need not be any intrinsic or "natural" interpretations of $+$ or $\cdot$.  So A) is not something to "prove" so much as something to *define*.  But if you do define it you must show it is well defined and that it is closed.  That is that $a+b$ will always equal a $c \in S$ and which $c$ will be distinct, consistent and unambiguous.

The additive axioms must hold.

1) $a + b = b + a$ for all $a,b \in S$.

2) $+$ is associative, that is $a+(b+c) = (a+b) + c$ for all $a,b,c \in A$.

3) There exists an additive identity $0 \in S$ so that for all $a\in S$ then $0 + a = a + 0 = a$.

4) For any $a \in S$ there exists an element $b \in S$ so that $a+b = b+a = 0$.  This is called the additive inverse.  The additive inverse of $a$ and written as $-a$.  $-a$ need not be distinct from $a$ ($-0 = 0$). The axiom doesn't state that an additive inverse needs to be unique but it is easily proven that it must be.  [If $a + b = 0$ and $a + c = 0$ then $b = b+ 0 = b + (a+c) = (b+a) + c= 0 + c = c$.]

The multiplicative axioms must hold.

1) $a\cdot b = b\cdot a$ for all $a,b\in S$.

2) $\cdot$ is associative.  $a\cdot(b\cdot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot d$

3) There exists a multiplicative identity $1 \in S$ and $1 \ne 0$ so that for all $a \in S$.  $1 \cdot a = a \cdot 1 = a$.

4) For any $a \in S$ where $a \ne 0$ there exists a $b \in S$ so that $ a\cdot b = b\cdot a = 1$.  $b$ is called the multiplicative inverse of $a$ and may be written as $\frac 1a$ or as $a^{-1}$.  Again the axiom doesn't indicate it is distinct ($1^{-1} = 1$) but it is easy to prove it is distinct for each $a \in S; a\ne 1$.

A finally you must show the distributive property

D) For all $a,b,c \in S$ then $a\cdot (b + c) = (a\cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$

So 11 things in all to show.

[Notation conventions (ex. that $a\cdot b + c $ is taken to mean $(a\cdot b) + c$ and not $a\cdot (b + c)$ etc.) follow but are not part of the axioms requiring proof.]